# Should files only be included at the point where they are needed or at the top?

Tags: php

I was wondering if it is better practice to include all files a PHP script could use at the top of the file or if it is better to only include the files when they are needed. Here is an example:

### Requiring in Header

```
require_once("../engine/generalGetter.php");

if($loggedIn) {     
    $currencyManager = new CurrencyManager();
}
```

### Requiring when Needed

```
if($loggedIn) {   
    require_once("../engine/generalGetter.php");
    $currencyManager = new CurrencyManager();
}
```

The first method has the benefit of keeping all includes organized, while the second method has the advantage of not loading unnecessary code into RAM. I am not sure which method is best for a turnkey script that could be modified by the user.

Comment: If these are class files, then use an autoloader and you get the best of both worlds

Comment: *1) only include the files when they are needed*, *2) second method has the advantage of not loading unnecessary code into RAM* **You only answered your question**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you do not want `require` statements littered throughout your code. That could quickly snowball into spaghetti code. Instead isolate all your requires to a single file, and automatically lazy load the required files when their respective classes are required.

**Recommendation:**

The PHP community recognized this issue several years ago and a group formed to propose standards for this, as well as other common issues (that group is [PHP-FIG](http://www.php-fig.org/)). The first proposal ([PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/)) was to address this "autoloading" issue. It was followed up later with another, [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

This standardization has been a boon to PHP development, and *will* make your life easier should you choose to adopt it. I would highly recommend using an off-the-shelf autoloader like [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) which will do a great job of automatically loading your PSR-0 or PSR-4 compliant code as well as serving as a package manager for community PHP code (most is on [packagist](https://packagist.org/)).

With an autoloader configured, you will only ever have a single call to `require()`, generally at the very top of your first executable file:

```
// file: index.php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$someInstance = new App\CurrencyManager();
```

Comment: Although I can't use this method due to simplicity being an important part of this script's value, this does answer my question and elaborates on the third option.